# Read/Write fixed length text records with carriage return row terminators

Tags: c#, text, random-access

Example of C# that implements this pseudo code w/o becoming "unmanaged":

```
dataRec = dataRec.Key [5] + dataRec.Ptr [5] + CrLf [2];
recSize = sizeof (dataRec); // recSize = 12
aCrLf = CarriageReturn (ASCII 13) + LineFeed (ASCII 10); // define CrLf constant
fs = Open (textFile);
dataRec = "A    " + "00001" + aCrLf; // initialize 1st Row
Write (fs, dataRec, recSize * (1 - 1), recsize); // write 1st row at offset 0
dataRec = "AB   " + "00002" + aCrLf; // initialize 2nd Row
Write (fs, dataRec, recSize * (2 - 1), recsize); // write 2nd row at offset 12
dataRec = "ABC  " + "00003" + aCrLf; // initialize 3rd Row
Write (fs, dataRec, recSize * (3 - 1), recsize); // write 3rd row at offset 24
//
Read (fs, dataRec, recSize * (1 - 1), recsize); // Read 1st row at offset 0
sWork = dataRec;    // convert to string.
Console.WriteLine(sWork);   // show 1st row
Read (fs, dataRec, recSize * (2 - 1), recsize); // Read 2nd row at offset 12
sWork = dataRec;    // convert to string.
Console.WriteLine(sWork);   // show 2nd row
Read (fs, dataRec, recSize * (3 - 1), recsize); // Read 3rd row at offset 24
sWork = dataRec;    // convert to string.
Console.WriteLine(sWork);   // show 3rd row
Close (fs);
```

Reading/writing fixed length text rows at an offset, i.e. random access, is very easy with DBL, C or VBA. But the C# examples I have seen of binary read/write use "unmanaged code" and none of the examples I have reviewed read/write text/flat files with CrLf row terminator at an offset.

Answer (score 0):

Really you have never seen code that use a StreamReader or File.ReadAllLines()?

```
    string path = @"d:\temp\testFile.txt";

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
         string[] loadedLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
         if(loadedLines.Length >= 5)
         {
              string line5 = loadedLines[4];
              if(line5.Length >= 10)
              {
                  string key = line5.Substring(0,5);
                  string value = line5.Substring(5,5);
                  .....
              }
         }
    }
```

The writing part could be this

```
     List<string> lines = loadedLines.ToList();
     lines.Add("00009VAL09");
     lines[4] = "00008XXXXX";
     File.WriteAllLines(path, lines);
```

Of course these methods (ReadAllLines/WriteAllLines) are not the best option when you have a very big file to read or write but it is really easy to work with text files in NET

**From MSDN**
[File.IO class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file_methods.aspx)
[Common IO tasks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404278.aspx)

Using a random access on a text file is a bit uncommon, however it is possible for example using the BinaryReader and a BinaryWriter classes.
In this example I try to position the file pointer on the fourth record of your file.

```
// The 5+5+2 is the assumed lenght of a line
const int recLength = 12;

string path = @"d:\temp\DATA1.txt";

if (File.Exists(path))
{
    int recNum = 4;

    string key;
    string value;
    using(BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        // The key point is the Position property that should be set using
        // some kind of simple math to the exact position needed
        br.BaseStream.Position = recNum * recLength;

        // Read the 5 bytes and build the key and value string, 
        // note that reading (or writing) advances the Position 
        key = new string(br.ReadChars(5));
        value = new string(br.ReadChars(5));
    }
    Console.WriteLine(key)        ;
    Console.WriteLine(value)        ;

    key = "00009";
    value = "KKKKK";

    using(BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
    {
        // Again the math required to position for the write
        bw.BaseStream.Position = recNum * recLength;
        bw.Write(key.ToCharArray());
        bw.Write(value.ToCharArray());
    }

}
```

Comment: The application uses a sorted index (the pseudo code suggests the sorted index) that "points to" a fixed location data record that can be relatively wide (up to 1,000 bytes with up to 50 fields/columns). The two files (index & data) can be VERY large.

Comment: ReadAllLines works for smaller files where the lines/rows don't have fields/columns. While size may not be a problem, each line/row can have up to 50 components/fields/columns. So, we need to be able to address (change, display) each field: recData.Field1 = "SomeValue";

Comment: COBOL, DIBOL & DBL (just a few languages that I am partially familiar with) use text files exclusively. Alphanumeric fields are left justified and numeric fields are right justified. What is missing from the BinaryReader/BinaryWriter is a record layout or file description that automatically provides the offsets. In our case, when we have 50 fields, something is needed to automatically know the offset of each field.

Comment: This FDS (File Description Specification) in C allows the ease of saying: Key = "ABC  "; or Ptr = "00002";typedef struct { /* expr.fds 012 bytes */
    BYTE key[5]; /* A05 - unique code */
    BYTE ptr[5]; /* D05 - pointer to data record */
    CRLF txt_cl; /* #02 - ASCII 13 + ASCII 10 */
} EXP_R;
#define EXPRSZ (sizeof(EXP_R))   Sorry, but I couldn't separate the code. :-(

Comment: At the best of my knowledge there is nothing directly in the NET framework to ease your duty. Of course, there are tons of classes in the library that could offer the building blocks for this kind of work. For example take a look at [Composite Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx) and to [string.Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.format.aspx)

Comment: And, it's bigger than addressing fields/columns in a row/record and then reading/writing the row/record. It's about addressing memory, in general. I am used to having a "common area" that is addressable. Parts of which are records/rows from files. I am used to being able to say: Common.A = File.A; (move all the fields in A that were read from File into A in the Common Area).

Comment: And, since we do random access reads & writes during the same process, using Stream or FileStream seems to fit better. Certainly, it seems cumbersome to have a read handle and a write handle.

Comment: MemoryMappedFile http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx shows an example that reads a part of a file into a "public struct", allows change, then writes the changes back to the file.